# What are ways of distinguishing objects of the same type for retrieval, comparison, etc in c#

Tags: c#, oop, object, enums, open-closed-principle

I apologize for the strange title, I wasn't sure how to ask the question, so If you have any suggestion as to what would be more appropriate, let me know and I'll update it.

Often when programming, I would use Enums as keys to dictionaries whos values are data relating to the enum. I'd usually do this before I realize that there would be lots of data associated with that enum, which would then lead me on to create a data type.

For example, I might have the enum:

```
public enum AreaKey
{
    Home,
    Hospital,
    Park,
    TrainStation
}
```

and then a dictionary (Vector2 being a class with 2 integers):

```
Dictionary<AreaKey, Vector2> areaCoordinatesByAreaKey;
```

Later down the line, I decide I want a bunch of other data associated with this area, so instead I build a new class called:

```
    public class Area
    {
        Vector2 coordinates;
        string name;
        // more data
    }
```

Now, to reference this data, I know I can just build a dictionary using the same enum as the key to retrieve the specified area, but this always feels cumbersome to me, and almost like it's not proper OOP.

I have the area objects. They have specific data that *should* make them unique from one and other. Why do I have to use an enum? Also I don't like having to break OCP everytime I realize I need a new area. It would be awesome to just be able to create an object and not have to worry about external management. order 1 retrieval is nice though.

Of course I could use a string key to retrieve it, but that means people have to know the strings and it's not very type safe... enums are easy to read. Help me stack overflow!

Comment: It largely depends on how you want to use them. Having a dictionary of `Area` objects keyed by `AreaKey` seems a little odd, because you will only ever have one area of each type.

Comment: This is unnecessary obfuscation. What's wrong with a normal class/instance with properties? They read like a charm. "Why do I have to use an enum?"... for this, you don't. I don't understand why you ever did.

Comment: I assume the use of `enum` stems from something related to "people have to know the strings". There's a whole part to this problem that you haven't really written about, which is how you got here in the first place (I imagine that it's some piece of UI from which users submit data).

Comment: Using a Dictionary that could only ever store 4 objects is a heavy code smell.  Hard to guess how this happened, brain-bugs tend to be hard to identify from a code snippet.  You're only half-way discovering that something went wrong, think some more.about object identity.

Comment: I think it might be related to the fact that we use singletons a lot in our code (not me personally, our team). The singleton would contain a bunch of data (like the Areas) and we would need to retrieve the areas, so we would use dictionaries with the enum key... Could this be related?

Comment: @spender there could be 100 areas, it would be cumbersome to write 100 class instances. Instead we group them into a container. Dictionary as opposed to an array so we can use enum to easily identify which one we are trying to retrieve. Maybe I should mention we are using a Game Engine (Unity) Where we can drag and drop our object references. We drag and drop them into a dictionary via an interface (so we don't have to implement each one in code)

Comment: Why does having 100 of them make it any more cumbersome? You still need to create the instances and have them in the dictionary: https://gist.github.com/evantrimboli/26b488b183234d0a64baaddc57f1046e

Comment: Okay I see now. This must be a purely programming environment specific issue. I'm programming within the Unity3D Game Engine. We can apply scripts to objects (Such as an Area script) - Here take a look for yourself: https://imgur.com/bOYE4ik On the left you have the enum and on the right you have the reference to the object... sorry honestly sometimes I get so confused what the hell Im struggling with

Comment: It could be that the overhead of using this method is all the problems I described... Maybe there's no way around it

Comment: Not sure about the Unity part, so I'll have to bow out at this point.

Comment: @EvanTrimboli Thanks for trying to help anyway, I understand my problem better now.

Answer (score 1):

It totally depends on how you intend to retrieve the object.  For example typically when creating WinForms apps (before I knew about the magic of *data binding*) and I have added items to say a `ListBox`, I might want to remember each object's position in the list so that I can retrieve it easily later.  I would create `Dictionary<Foo, int>`.  Similarly, I may want to allow quick lookup based on the position in the list so I would have a `Dictionary<int, Foo>`.  In other words **don't** try to **store everything** into **one `Dictionary<>`.**  Define them by use case.

You have already defined one by `AreaKey` and this assumes no two objects have the same enum and so using a dictionary in this case makes sense.  However, I think you are going down the wrong track trying to put everything into one key.  Instead you might want to have another `Dictionary<string, Area>` where it refers to the `Area.name` so that not only can  you lookup by enum, but also by name.

Later  you might want to add `PostCode` so again another `Dictionary<int, Area>` makes sense.

In summary, define:

```
Dictionary<string, Area> mapAreasByName;
Dictionary<int, Area> mapAreasByPostCode;

var area = mapAreasByName["New York"];
area = mapAreasByPostCode[2000];
```